How should we calculate L (inductance) value for a transformer
I am trying to design a transformer using LTSpice with the following specifications:

Vin = 230 V @ 50 Hz
Vout = 12 V @ 50 Hz
Power = 10 W

The thing I do not understand is how to calculate the inductance (L) value for these specifications. I know there are some formulas  (N1 / N2 = V1 / V2), but how do we determine L1? How can we calculate it?

For what purpose? Are you modeling a particular transformer? Show the datasheet. Do you know what magnetizing current or leakage it should have? Do you need a generic mostly-ideal transformer to support a circuit, nothing in particular?

Thank you for the answer. I do not have a particular transformer to simulate so that ı do not have a datasheet. I just want to learn how can we calculate these values and to be honestly ı do not know what should be the magnetizing current or leakage inductance. But ı want to calculate  a basic model transformer  maybe with a leakage and magnetizing current

A starting point would be 20 % magnetizing current of your full rated load, in this case 2 VA. At 230 V, that’s 8.6 mA. Z = 2*Pi*L*f. Solve for L.
If the transformer would have been 2 kW, about 5 % would be reasonable to assume for general purpose.

Thank you for this detailed information. Can you help me to solve these equations with step by step Winny. I could not understand some points. For example Z

Z = U(rms)/I(rms). In this case 230/8.6m.

Why we have not found L by the help of 10/230 = 43.7mA. Did you mean Lm with L?

We did indirectly as Lm is related to the full load current. Yes, Lm.

The inductance is essentially a characteristic of the transformer core, and rises with the square of the number of turns.  If you study the datasheet for a particular core you should find this value known as AL (expressed as Henries/turn^2) and you should also find the maximum magnetisation, expressed in Tesla.  The latter can be used to determine the maximum throughput of the transformer.

Can you help me to do a basic calculation? the values that you mentioned

@TechnoLover you’ll need to start by specifying a core.

Looking at this RM10: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3920295.pdf the untapped version using N95 compound has an AL value of 5500nH per turn^2, so for example 100 turns would give you 55mH.
